# I can't make run the blemanager.start because promise rejection id:0 null is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-manager

I can't start the ble manager in my code.
I use expo.
I tried a lot of solutions I found on internet but none worked for me.
When i get out the blemanager.start my app run correctly.
I don't find any kind of doc about promise in React native... There is my code. I really hope you can help me.

```
import { Stylesheet, View, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity,FlatList, Alert,NativeAppEventEmitter } from 'react-native'
import donnee from '../Donnee/data'
import DataItem from './DataItem'
import FilmDetail from './FilmDetail';
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
//import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-plx';
const width_proportion = '60%';
const Lwidth_proportion = '30%';
const maxwidth="100%";
const heightinside="12%";
const paddleft = '10%';
class Search extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('bluetooth scanner mounted');
    NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',(data) => 
    {
        let device = 'device found: ' + data.name + '(' + data.id + ')'; 
        if(this.devices.indexOf(device) == -1) {
            this.devices.push(device);
        }
        let newState = this.state;
        newState.dataSource = newState.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.devices);
        this.setState(newState);
    });
    BleManager.start({ showAlert: false }).then(() => {
        // Success code
        console.log("Module initialized");
      });
}
  startScanning() {
    console.log('start scanning');
}
    render() {
        return (
        <View>
          <View style={styles.entete}></View>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.filtrebtn}  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("FilmDetail")}>
              <Text style = {styles.textfiltre}>FILTRES</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.scan}  onPress={() => this.startScanning()}>
              <Text style = {styles.textscan}>SCAN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View>
               <FlatList 
               data={donnee} 
               keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()} 
               renderItem={({item}) =><DataItem donnees={item}/> }  />
          </View>
        </View>
          
        )
    }
}
export default Search
```

Comment: https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/tree/master/example should contain a full working example using the ble manager :) maybe you can find your solution there!

Comment: I use expo, this is a problem ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I assumed you are using flutter. I'm not sure if it's going to be a problem. Just have a look at the example, maybe you find something that's missing from your code

Comment: I don't find anythings really good about my problem, i don't find how to use a ble manager

Comment: The ble manager is being used in https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/master/example/App.js

Comment: Thanks, it really help me. But I have a bug about the promise rejection ( null is not an object)

Comment: I use the code you gave me. And i only have one warning about the promise rejection

Answer (score 0):

expo can not work with the ble-manager. You need to use the native package by running the

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

and you need mac not a window